# Implementing Quick Action buttons in Email templates in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, email-templates, salesforce-lightning

We are new to Salesforce and we are trying to implement Quick action buttons in HTML Email templates of Salesforce.

**Our scenario is** -
 When an opportunity is submitted for approval, we are sending an email to approvers. This email is generated using an Email Template, which has some text and a couple of links. Approvers receive this email and clicks on the reply button and then reply with 'Approved' or 'Rejected' words which are sent to Salesforce and opportunity is approved or rejected accordingly.

**What we are trying to achieve?** -
Instead of approvers replying by typing 'Approved' or 'Rejected' manually, we want to have Quick action buttons on the bottom of the email, upon clicking on them, it should type the text automatically as the reply. Please see the screenshot.[image: This is how it works in Gmail.]

What we have already tried? - In our Salesforce email approval HTML template, we have added the HTML code for buttons and applied Javascript in them to create a response, the code is below. We are getting error - Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src xyz.com 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

```
<input type="button" style=" font: bold 11px Arial;
      background-color: #4BCA81;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px 6px 5px 6px;
      border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
      border-right: 1px solid #333333;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
      border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;" 
      class="button" value="Approve" onclick="generateReply('Approved')"/>
<input type="button" style=" font: bold 11px Arial;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: #E1553C;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px 6px 5px 6px;
      border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
      border-right: 1px solid #333333;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
      border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;" href="https://cgdstudios2017-- 
      pdg.lightning.force.com/apex/RejectDeal?id={!Opportunity.Id}" 
      class="button" value="Reject" onclick="generateReply('Rejected')"/>`
```

The output that we are able to generate as Email is

[image: This is our email template output, we want the buttons to be functional.]

Please let us know if anyone has any idea about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript does not work on any popular email clients. This will never work. You can have a url linked to each button to give approval and rejection.

Comment: Thank you @gwally, but I have implemented it using some custom solution, I will post that as an answer once that is implemented.